# Recursively render handlebars templates using Ember CLI

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I have a tree like structure of comments I would like to render using handlebars in Ember CLI. Each comment can have an infinite set of replies, with each reply having an infinite amount of replies, much like you have on reddit. I have the following file 'comments.hbs'.

```
<div class="comments">
{{#each comments}}
    <div class="comment">
        <span><b>{{author}}</b></span> <span>{{showdown-addon text}}</span>
    </div>

    {{recursively-call-this-template-somehow-with-new-context replies}}
{{/each}}
</div>
```

Anyone have any idea how I can do this with Ember CLI? I've seen some solutions using {{> template-name}} but haven't managed to get it working.

Comment: I see that you rarely provide feedback to the answers in your questions. If an answer has been helpful you can up-vote it to say thanks and mark it as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use an `ArrayController` that renders itself again if a list of replies is available.

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yamudi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Be aware that [the render helper creates a singleton controller](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_render). I don't think it matters in this particular example, but it could become an issue if you decide to add to 'CommentsController'.

Comment: Yeah, but if you provide a `model` arg (the example does), then a new controller instance is created :D

Comment: Wow, I must have skipped right over that part. Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, that example put me on the right track. Though when I implemented it in Ember CLI. I had to make some mods to the _comment template. The first iteration values are wrapped up in a model object `{{model.author}}` but all subsequent iterations are accessed like `{{author}}` when I finish my example fully I'll add an edit to my original question